# Issues with $(selector).load working randomly in Opera browser only

Tags: jquery, dom, opera, document-ready

I want to fade in some images while hidden on page load with CSS (display: none;).
This works **fine** on Firefox, Chrome, Safari, 
On Opera (last version: 12.12), the img are shown randomly...

Here is the Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('img:hidden').load(function () {
            $('img:hidden').fadeIn(1000);
        });
    });
```

Has anybody an idea of why it's randomly working on Opera ?

Thanks

Comment: hmmm, doesn't .load need a url?

Comment: I maybe should rename the title of my post because the problem was .load ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, "load" event triggers better, if an image is visible.
Besides, from my own experience, in some cases (IE for example) the following trick helps to solve an issue.

```
$(document).ready( function() {

  if ( $.browser.opera ) {
    $('img:hidden').each( function() {
      $('img:hidden').fadeIn(1000);
    });
  }
  else {
    $('img:hidden').load( function() {
      $('img:hidden').fadeIn(1000);
    });
  }

});
```

Comment: thanks your code works great in all browsers! I used (without testing the browser):
   $('img:hidden').each( function() {
      $('img:hidden').fadeIn(1000);
    });

Comment: `$.browser` is deprecated and already removed in 1.9 so this code will break rather sooner than later. And I cannot see how this should solve the issue in Opera? Mind explaining a little further?

Comment: Christoph, I'm not a jQuery team member, so I can't explain, why it helps. As I wrote, it's "from my own experience" - that means, that I found this approach occasionally, working on a website and having a similar problem (but with IE, not opera). BTW, the key feature of this code is not $.browser check, as you might think, but replacing .load() by .each().

Answer (score 0):

Well, you cannot really miss the according note in the jQuery Docu. The fontsize is like [500px](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)...perhaps too large to recognize? ;-D

> Caveats of the load event when used with images
>
> A common challenge
> developers attempt to solve using the .load() shortcut is to execute a
> function when an image (or collection of images) have completely
> loaded. There are several known caveats with this that should be
> noted. These are:
>
> It doesn't work consistently nor reliably
> cross-browser
>
> It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is
> set to the same src as before
>
> It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM
> tree
>
> Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's
> cache

Comment: lol yes I just checked the "newly redesigned" jQuery website and it's really written BIG :)